# Ecto migrations ownership timeout

Tags: elixir, ecto

Sometimes when my Ecto migrations run in CI (which builds the db from scratch, and sometimes has long pauses not caused by our code), they time out, with an error like:

> 10:05:01.828 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.5572.0>) disconnected: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) owner #PID<0.89.0> timed out because it owned the connection for longer than 15000ms

I can reproduce this locally by adding a `:timer.sleep(15_000)` to any individual migration. I can also reproduce it by adding shorter `timer.sleep/1` calls to several different migrations, which seems to show that there's a single time limit for running all migrations.

I can fix this locally by configuring the `ownership_timeout` for the repo:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  # ...other configurations...
  ownership_timeout: 60_000 # or whatever
```

With this setting, migrations run successfully even with the `:timer.sleep/1` calls above. But I don't want this setting to apply in most cases.

How can I specify an `:ownership_timeout` to use **only** when running migrations?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Application.put_env/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Application.html#put_env/4):

```rb
app_env = Application.get_env(:my_app, MyApp.Repo, [])
# temporary advance the timeout
Application.put_env(
  :my_app,
  MyApp.Repo,
  Keyword.merge(app_env, [ownership_timeout: 60_000])
)
# run migrations
path = Application.app_dir(:my_app, "priv/repo/migrations")
Ecto.Migrator.run(MyApp.Repo, path, :up, all: true)
# restore setting
Application.put_env(:my_app, MyApp.Repo, app_env)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to define a new config for your migrations. This way you can still run them via `mix ecto.migrate`

```
# config/migrations.exs

use Mix.Config
import_config("prod.exs")

config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  ownership_timeout: 60_000
```

You can run your migrations now via `MIX_ENV=migrations mix ecto.migrate`.

Comment: This is handier during development but I do not see any way to use this approach in production. Am I missing something? One cannot switch environments during deploy, especially during hot-reload deploy.

Comment: Huh, good point, there is no way to get that info when abusing `MIX_ENV`. You could exchange the "dev" to "prod" since it seems like it's just happening when being in the CI env. But your solution is probably better suited in general use-cases

Answer (score 0):

### A custom Mix alias

Building on @mudasobwa's answer, I made a [mix alias](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html#module-aliases) that modifies the configuration temporarily, then runs the normal migration task.

In `mix.exs`:

```
defmodule Coach.Umbrella.Mixfile do
# other stuff...

  defp aliases do
    [
      "ecto.migrate": &migrate_with_long_timeout/1
    ]
  end

  defp migrate_with_long_timeout(_) do
    IO.inspect "prove that my custom task is running"
    app_env = Application.get_env(:coach_domain, CoachDomain.Repo, [])
    # Temporarily increase the timeout
    Application.put_env(
      :coach_domain,
      CoachDomain.Repo,
      Keyword.merge(app_env, [ownership_timeout: 60_000])
    )
    Mix.Task.run("ecto.migrate")
    # Restore normal configuration
    Application.put_env(:coach_domain, CoachDomain.Repo, app_env)
  end
end
```

Note that aliases are project-specific. Eg, in an umbrella project, whether you define this in the top-level directory or an app-specific directory determines where you will be able to run it from.

Comment: This won’t work in production (at least not with `delivery`.) If you want a local-only solution, use @JonasDellinger’s answer, it’s way cleaner.

Comment: Good point. But this works locally in both dev and test, and in CI in test. In prod, I don't expect to be running all migrations from the beginning in one shot.

Comment: `Ecto` is smart enough to skip already applied migrations. This line is safe to run and this is exactly how it’s supposed to be deployed to production (and that’s how I deploy.)

Comment: @mudasobwa Sorry, my comment wasn't clear. The reason I'm getting this timeout in CI is that it runs all migrations from the beginning to build the db from scratch. We also sometimes do that in development. So in both cases, we could run into the timeout. But in production we would not run all migrations because there would be existing data and, as you said, ecto will only run the newest ones. So I wouldn't expect to run into the timeout there. In dev and CI, `mix` is available.